# How to use custom logger with Logback and SLF4J

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I have existing project with very standart Logback implementation.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

class SomeClass{

  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

  void someMethod(){
     log.info("some log message");
  }
}
```

This is used in many places and in code I dont have sources. `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` is used as implementation.

I want to use my own implementation of Logger (I wanted to extend `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` but it's final) and use it applicatio wide without modifying the code (which I don't have anyway).

I would expect that configuration of `LoggerFactory` in `logback.xml` would be possible, but it doesn't seem so.

I'm using maven artifacts

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
   <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I could not find straight way of doing it. I came over XLogger and logback-ext but it seems I would need to modify all factory usages.

Comment: `I want to use my own implementation of Logger ` why ?

Comment: That's not part of this question, but i need to analyse stack and log extra data in some cases to tacke with peculiar memory leak. Does this help?

Comment: You can set log level as lowest as 'TRACE' by using logback.xml. If you are looking into memory leak, best approach is by generating a heap dump and analyze it with tool or use a memory profiler like https://www.eclipse.org/mat/